# TinyMce focus in Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, focus, tinymce

i have an issue with chrome and tinymce. To set the focus into the editor i do:

```
tinyMCE.getInstanceById('my_editor_id').focus();
```

It works fine in FF and IE. Why not in chrome?

This does not work at all:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceFocus', false, 'my_editor_id');
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I think `focus()` is not properly supported in Chrome. I would recommend using `click()`

Comment: when i use click() following error appears: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'click'

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
setup: function(ed){
   ed.onInit.add(function(ed){
      $(ed.getDoc()).contents().find('body').focus(function(){tinymce_focus();});
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me. I create a focus event listener that causes a focus. I am not sure if this is creating an infinite loop but it is working without any problems.

```
// Chrome Hack
var addEvent = function(node,eventName,func){

      if ("undefined" == typeof node || null == node) {              
      } else {
          if (!node.ownerDocument.addEventListener && node.ownerDocument.attachEvent) {
              node.attachEvent('on' + eventName, func);
          } else node.addEventListener(eventName,func,false);
      }
}; 

var cur = ed.dom.select('textarea'); // select all tinymce textareas
for(var idx=0;idx<cur.length;idx++) {           
    addEvent(cur[idx],'focus',function(evt) {
            evt = evt ? evt : window.event;                             
            evt.target.focus();
            return true;                                
        });
}
```